# how to print variable in c struct

Tags: c, runtime

Please am finding it difficult to print variable b in my struct declaration

```
sum.h
#ifndef SUM_H_
#define SUM_H_

typedef struct sumTAG{
  int a;
  int b;    
}Sum;

void addition();
void initialize();

#endif
```

sumtest.c

```
#include "../headers/sum.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void initialize(Sum *S){
  S->a = 10;
  S->b = 10;
}

void addition(Sum* s){

  printf("the value of a is : ", s->a);

}

int main(){

  Sum *sum;
  initialize(sum);
  addition(sum);

  return 0;
}
```

I keep getting a runtime error with return value of **225**;

Comment: You have not allocated any memory for `sum`.

Comment: so please how do i go about it? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: `Sum sum;
  initialize(&sum);
  addition(&sum);`

Comment: `printf("the value of a is : ", s->a);` --> `printf("the value of a is %d: ", s->a);`

Comment: when i do that warnings are been generated, although the code get executed @BLUEPIXY.

Comment: please what is the deference between *sum, sum and &sum@Arik

Comment: I did not get any warnings [overall sample code](http://ideone.com/fT1Cfd)

Comment: Ok@BLUEPIXY I do in my Devc++ ide

Answer (score 3):

```
Sum *sum;
```

is a pointer to nowhere, until you set it to point to something.
It could point to an allocated memory:

```
Sum *sum = malloc(sizeof(Sum));
```

Which is probably what you want to do in your case.
But it could also point to a local variable,

```
Sum sum;
Sum *pointerToSum = &sum;
initialize(pointerToSum);
addition(pointerToSum);
```

The error you get is probably due to trying to dereference a null pointer.